# Sum of the Time elapsed during the transition from OFF to ON, group by the day

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to know  the time elapsed when state changes from OFF to ON and create the sum of the these elapsed for each day.
Final outcome should look like(example dataframe):

```
[Date             Elapsed_Time (min)
2021 05 01          200  
2021 05 02          340
2021 05 03           0][1]
```

For the missing dates it can be given a value of zero.

the data for state changes and the time when it is updated:

```
state   last _updated
on      4/30/2021 16:04
on      4/30/2021 16:05
off     5/1/2021 1:00
off     5/1/2021 2:57
off     5/1/2021 2:58
off     5/1/2021 3:09
off     5/1/2021 3:10
off     5/1/2021 3:14
off     5/1/2021 3:15
off     5/1/2021 8:25
off     5/1/2021 8:26
off     5/1/2021 9:02
off     5/1/2021 9:03
on      5/1/2021 13:00
on      5/1/2021 14:00
on      5/1/2021 14:01
on      5/1/2021 14:08
on      5/1/2021 14:11
```

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: i have tried this:
`d6['Elapsed_Time'] = (d6.groupby(d6.state.eq(0).cumsum()).time.transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.total_seconds().cumsum().div(60)).fillna(0))`

The problem with this is this just seems the oFF to ON state and does not consider the date. So if their is OFF on day 1 and a OFF on Next day then it calculates that too, which is not required.

Comment: The data in expected output does not correspond to the sample input data.  Please either elaborate the calculation logics or craft better data input / output samples.  Otherwise, we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To get you starting you can do something like this:

(I created a shorter table with data...)

```
DROP TABLE if exists states;
CREATE TABLE states (
   state CHAR(4), 
   last_updated datetime);
   
INSERT INTO states VALUES
   ('on', '2021-04-30 16:04'),
   ('on', '2021-04-30 16:05'),
   ('off', '2021-05-01 01:00'),
   ('off', '2021-05-01 02:57'),
   ('on', '2021-05-01 13:00');
   
SELECT
   state,
   CASE WHEN state <> lag(state) over (order by last_updated Desc) 
        THEN TIMEDIFF(lag(last_updated) over (order by last_updated desc),last_updated)
        ELSE null END as X
FROM states
order by last_updated;
```

output:

```
+ ---------- + -------- +
| state      | X        |
+ ---------- + -------- +
| on         |          |
| on         | 08:55:00 |
| off        |          |
| off        | 10:03:00 |
| on         |          |
+ ---------- + -------- +
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am looking for implementation in python and not SQL , I am using jupyter notebook to resolve this.